# How to Add\Edit ECK entitys from front-end?

Tags: 7, users, entities

I'm using the [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module for defining custom entities. Also there are users that have permissions to add and edit entities from specific bundle. I'm trying to create a front-end menu for these users with 'Add entity' and 'Edit entity' items.

My question: how to provide an option to Add/edit custom entities to the front-end users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECK create CRUD permissions for all entity type/bundles that has been created with it, so all you need to do is to give the users the permissions needed.

Since the path is located in admin/ you might need to create a link for users to use to create some of your custom entities.